# Why this algorithm gives an eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have a square matrix $A$ having the properties:

1) $a_{ij} a_{ji} = 1$

2) $a_{ii}=1$

3) $a_{ij}=a_{ik}a_{kj}$.

If the last condition is not satisfied, then anyway I get a pretty good approximation of an eigenvector using the method below. So the method to obtain an eigenvector of matrix $A$ (with all positive elements, not sure if it works with negative as well):

1) divide every element in a given column by the sum of elements in that column (normalization)

2) calculate average of elements in each row of the matrix obtained in step 1).

Why this method works? Is it only an approximation of an eigenvector? Matrix $A$ can have multiple eigenvectors, so which one am I getting here?

Comment: If you start with a matrix with rational coefficients, then you get a vector with rational coefficients. Yet there are matrices with positive rational coefficients whose eigenvectors do not have rational coefficients, like $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: This example shows that there is no finite sequence of steps involving algebraic operations (sum, products, differences, quotients) which starting with the entries of the matrix will produce an eigenvector.

Comment: @Winther these conditions are apparently meant to hold for all i,j,k. No summation convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I have not understood your process.

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}$
$A' = \begin{pmatrix} 2/5 & 1/3 \\ 3/5 & 2/3\end{pmatrix}$

"eigenvector" $ v= \begin{pmatrix} 11/30 \\ 19/30\end{pmatrix}$

But is easy to see that $v$ is not an eigenvector of $A$.

---

It turns out that you are correct and this method will produce eigenvectors. I'll also show that such a matrix has an eigenvalue equal to $n$ (the dimension of the matrix) and the eigenvector you're calculating is associated with the eigenvalue $n$.

**Proof**

Let $a_{ij}$ be the elements of our $n \times n$ matrix $A$.
The elements of $A'$, the modified matrix, is $$A'_{ij} = \frac{a_{ij}}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}}$$

And the element of the vector is $$v_i = \sum_{j=1}^n A'_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_{ij}}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}}$$

(Notice that I don't take the average but just the sum because if $v$ is an eigenvector also $\lambda v$ is for every $\lambda$.. so dividing by $n$ here to take the average would be useless)

Now let's calculate $(Av)_i$, the $i$-th element of the vector $Av$. We would like this to be equal to some constant times $v_i$.

$$(Av)_i = \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}v_j = \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_{jk}}{\sum_{i=1}^na_{ik}}\right)$$

Since $a_{ij}$ does not depend on $k$ I can bring it inside the parenthesis and obtain

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_{ij}a_{jk}}{\sum_{i=1}^na_{ik}} = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_{ik}}{\sum_{i=1}^na_{ik}}$$

Now nothing depends upon $j$ so it simplifies to

$$n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_{ik}}{\sum_{i=1}^na_{ik}} = nv_i$$

So we showed that $$Av = nv$$

so $n$ is an eigenvalue and $v$ one of the corresponding eigenvectors.

*Further questions:*

It looks like (and it would be nice to prove) that the characteristic polynomial for such a matrix is $P_x(A) = x^n - nx^{n-1}$
Also, is such a matrix diagonalizable?

Maybe I'll try to solve this problems sometime :-)

Comment: OMG, I forgot about the addiitonal properties a square matrix needs to satisfy for it to work. Question edited.

Comment: Added additional condition. Notice if the 3rd condition isn't satisfied, then anyway we get a good approximation of one of the eigenvectors.

Comment: @user4205580 What the third condition means? Who is $k$?

Comment: It means that, for example, $a_{23}$ has to be equal $a_{24}a_{43}$. $k$ is just any number between $1$ and number of rows (columns) of our square matrix $A$. All elements of the matrix need to satisfy this property - no matter what $k$ I choose (between $1$ and number of rows (columns).

Comment: @user4205580 I think I have showed that indeed your method works. Also, $n$ is an eigenvalue of such a matrix. Tell me what you think :-) By the way, how did you come up with such a construction for $v$? :-)

Comment: This method is used in Analytic Hierarchy Process: http://www.booksites.net/download/coyle/student_files/AHP_Technique.pdf , http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/AHP/Priority%20Vector.htm But none of these sources explain why it works (or I can't find it there). [Here](http://www.isahp.org/2001Proceedings/Papers/065-P.pdf) in the introduction it says the method is explained in the article, but maybe it's to complex for me to understand.

Comment: @user4205580 I see.. Let me know if you're satisfied with the answer :)

Comment: Yes, I believe it's fine. If you are interested, maybe you could try to answer my [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272705/consistent-matrix-eigenvectors-ahp-method) (after taking a look at the materials I gave). In the description of AHP method they often mention Perron-Frobenius theorem (I have no idea what's the connection between AHP and this theorem though...)

Comment: @user4205580 maybe I'll take a look at it after :)

Comment: I've started a bounty in that question if that motivates you. I expect an intuitive explanation of why the mathematics they talk about in the articles is used.

Comment: Now what I'm asking about should be more clear - I've rewritten the question.

Comment: I'd be very grateful if you could prove the other direction of [theorem 2.2 here](http://books.google.com/books?id=wct10TlbbIUC&lpg=PP1&hl=eng&pg=PT50#v=onepage&q&f=false). - if it's an eigenvector with eigenvalue $n$, then the matrix is consistent. The author of this book ommited the proof saying 'it's clear'. Well, not quite, at least for me. Maybe a little sketch of why this is true?

Comment: @user4205580 ask a separate question and include the relevant quote directly in your post. However it's probably missing some requirements because as it is the statement is not true; the 2x2 matrix with only 2 on the diagonal and everywhere else 0 has eigenvalue equal to 2 but clearly is not consistent

Comment: What about this particular case (I'm talking about what you've proven)? I believe the opposite implication is also true, that is if $v$ is the eigenvector with eigenvalue $n$, then the matrix is consistent - $a_{ij}=a_{ik}a_{kj}$. That would make your proof 'stronger', we would have a 'if and only if' relation.

Comment: @user4205580 in my previous comment I already said that this is not true. The matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$ has eigenvalue equal to $2$ but it's not consistent. So the "if and only if" relation simply does not hold. You need additional hypothesis. Maybe I'll take the time in the future to look at theorem 2.2 but right now I'm a little busy :-)

Comment: Yes, but this time we want to show that if $v$, defined as above in your proof ($v_i$ etc. at the beginning), is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $n$, then the matrix is consistent. Yeah, it doesn't hold for any eigenvector.

Comment: But this is, I believe, very easy - $\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_{ij}a_{jk}}{\sum_{i=1}^na_{ik}} = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_{ik}}{\sum_{i=1}^na_{ik}}$ is satisfied only if the matrix is consistent. It's enough to read the proof from the beginning, starting with $Av$ and from the end, in reverse order, until we arrive at this equality. Again, it's satisfied if and only if the matrix is consistent. I think you can agree?

Comment: @Ant It's quite easy to prove that such matrices has characteristic polynomial what you've given above, and yes, they are also diagonalizable, because they have $n-1$ zero eigenvalue and $1$ eigenvalue that is $n$.

Comment: Came back to this, because I think there's a mistake in your proof: you say that $(Av)_i = \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}v_j = \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_{jk}}{\sum_{i=1}^na_{ik}}\right)$, but that's not how you defined $v_j$ above (the first index of $a$ is different) - $v_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_{ij}}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}}$.

Comment: @user4205580 the index name is meaningless. $k$ or $j$ are only there to indicate the sum, the result does not depend on them. Just like the result of an integral does not depend on the name you give to the variable of integration

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all $A$ must be a positive matrix, because only the [Perron–Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) guarantees, that the spectral radius of $A$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a consitent pairwise comparison matrix, then $A$ is a rank one matrix, because it has one nonzero eigenvalue, which is $n$. Because of that any row or column of $A$ is an eigenvector of $A$, corresponding to $n$, and of course any of their linear combinations are this eigenvector too. Specially the arithmetic mean of the rows is an eigenvector. This eigenvector is called Perron eigenvector, and it is unique within a positive multiplicative constant.

The avarage what you've calculated differs within a positive multiplicative constans from any rows of columns.

If $A$ is not consistent, then $A$ has rank more than one, so this argumentation is false.